# Adding multiple UIButtons to an UIView

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview, uibutton

I've added some buttons to an UIView (via addSubview) programmatically. However, they appear as overlays (so that I always see the last button only). How do I add new buttons below existing buttons?

Regards

Comment: Could you clarify the question by stating which axis you are referring to when you say 'below'?

Comment: Yes, I meant the y-axis.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can offset the button like this

```
int newX = previousButton.frame.origin.x + previousButton.frame.size.width ;
int newY = previousButton.frame.origin.y ;
```

and either set the frame for new button when you create it:

```
[[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(newX,newY,100,100)];
```

or set the frame later

```
newButton.frame = CGRectMake(newX,newY,100,100);
```

Comment: What a coincidence, I made a similar solution at the same time ;-)
Here is mine: roundedButton.frame = CGRectMake(previousFrame.origin.x + previousFrame.size.width + 5, 0,  200,30);

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Set the UIView's frame origin to layout the UIButtons in the locations you wish:

```
CGRect buttonFrame = button.frame;
buttonFrame.origin = CGPointMake(100.0f, 100.0f);
button.frame = buttonFrame;
view.addSubview(button);
```

Comment: You'll need to add "button.frame = buttonFrame;" after line 2 or 3 to make this work. Otherwise, you're just modifying a copy of the frame rectangle.

Answer (score 2):

You can either use the insertSubview:atIndex method or insertSubview:belowSubview of your view.

```
UIButton *myButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,100,100)];

[myView insertSubview:myButton belowSubview:previousButton];
```

OR

```
[myView insertSubview:myButton atIndex:0];
```

Comment: I was uncertain whether Stefan was referring to the Y or Z axis - but between us we have covered both.

Comment: Couldn't really figure that out either, but like you said we took care of both.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answers guys.

I did the (horizontal) align with this code:

```
if([myContainer.subviews lastObject] == nil){
        NSLog(@"NIL");
        [myContainer insertSubview:roundedButton atIndex:0];
    }else{
        [myContainer insertSubview:roundedButton belowSubview:[tagsContainer.subviews lastObject]];
    }
```

It works technically, but still overlays the buttons. I have to find a way, how to not overlay them...

Comment: What do you mean overlay the buttons?

Comment: They appear visually as one button, because the are still on the same position (0.0, 0.0). So, my aim is to get the new starting position from the previous UIButton ([myContainer.subviews lastObject]). I think it has something to do with the UIButtons frame. But I don't know, how to get the positions.