# Adding multiple UIButtons to the same UIView only shows the last added button?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Why is this?

I've already seen a post about this issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1058760/adding-multiple-uibuttons-to-an-uiview), but I'm already considering that the button is to be created in a different x/y position.

Here's what I'm doing:

```
UIButton * bt1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
bt1.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 20, 20);

[bt1 setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:bt1];

UIButton * bt2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
bt2.frame = CGRectMake(80, 80, 20, 20);

[bt1 setTitle:@"B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:bt2];
```

Thank you!

Comment: you have bt1 instead of bt2

Comment: This code works. If you are having an issue with it, you need to include more context and detailed description of the issue that you are experiencing.

Comment: @nielsbot, you're right, he's setting properties on btn1 twice, but both buttons are created and if you run the code, both buttons appear in the view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have typo there, after allocating and creating button bt2, you are setting all things for bt1

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in the code. The only thing you might want to change is, you are setting the properties(title and target) of `bt1` two times and you are not setting those for `bt2`.

Comment: Fixed! Thank you, Apurv =)

Answer (score 1):

Dead simple way to prevent this from happening with local variables in the same scope: Use another scope.

```
{
UIButton * bt1 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
bt1.frame = CGRectMake(40, 40, 20, 20);

[bt1 setTitle:@"A" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:bt1];
}

{
UIButton * bt2 = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
bt2.frame = CGRectMake(80, 80, 20, 20);

[bt1 setTitle:@"B" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[bt1 addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPushed) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

[self.view addSubview:bt2];
}
```

The compiler will catch the error for you.

Comment: This is a very interesting approach! Thank you =)